# unable to ssh the ubuntu EC2 instance on macOS - Permission denied(Public Key)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am unable to SSH to the Ubuntu EC2 instance on AWS from macOS terminal.
Tried the following cmd from the terminal :

ssh ubuntu@ec2-13-127-143-37.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com

And

ssh 13.127.143.37@ec2-13-127-143-37.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
both are giving the same error: Permission denied (publickey).

I tried generating the public key using ssh-keygen and imported it under the key pair options on AWS, but still getting the same error.

Please help me with this.

Thanks,
Nidhi Arora

Answer (score 0):

The command in terminal should be something along the lines of:

```
ssh -i /path/to/yourkey.pem username@10.0.0.1
```

Don't forget too you need specific permissions on "yourkey.pem" - `chmod 400 yourkey.pem` - Reference to answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115838/what-is-the-right-file-permission-for-a-pem-file-to-ssh-and-scp)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't providing the private key when you establish the connection. You can download your private key when you launch the instance. Navigate to the folder where your private key is saved and run the following command. This is to ensure your private key is not publicly viewable. SSH will not work without this.

`chmod 400 private-key.pem`

Your final command should look something like this

`ssh -i "private-key.pem" ec2-user@ec2-13-127-143-37.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

On the pane listing your EC2 instances, if you select your instance, the 'Connect' button will get activated. If you click on that, it will give you the connection instructions specific to your instance. Attached screenshot of the button  below.

[image: The Connect button]

Comment: Oh good. Btw, you can choose an answer as the correct answer by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer. So it will be helpful for others who face the same problem as your question.